# How to setup bluetooth tethering with iPhone?

Tags: bluetooth, iphone, tethering

How do I use my iPhone as a wireless internet source using Bluetooth?

Answer (score 5):

This is how I achieved it.

- First don't forget to enable tethering in iPhone settings
- Use blueman (`sudo aptitude blueman`), it is more userfriendly
- In blueman settings make sure that in "Local services" PAN support switch in "NetworkManager"
- In blueman plugins settings make sure that NMPanSupport is enabled (and MNIntegration is disabled)
- Pair Blueman with iPhone as you would do with any other device
- After iPhone is connected, right click on it in Blueman main screen and connect to "Network Access Point" service.
- You're online, congratulations!